# NodeJS with Routes wont Post and returns a 404 Exception

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes

I'm making a simple blog post, but when I press submit, it only prints an array of what I entered on my form on the console. And I'm getting returned a 404 on my landing page after pressing the submit.

This is my form `ejs`:

```html
<form class="form-container" method="POST">
 <div id="logs">
  <div class="group">
   <input id="title" type="title" name="title" required>
   <label for="title" id="title1">Email</label>
   <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-8">
    <input type="date" name="date" id="dateToday" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="group">
   <input id="blogcont" type="text" name="blogcont" required>
   <label for="password" id="label2">Blog Content</label>
   <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="submitdiv">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit Blog" id="sub" formaction="sucess">
   <p class="regbutt">registration</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

---

This is my `app.js` file (404 error handler is returned from this file)

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config()
const pages = require('./pages');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const session = require('express-session')
const regroutr = require('./routes/regRoutes');
const logroutr = require('./routes/logRoutes');
const blgroutr = require('./routes/internalroutes')
const passport = require('passport');
const app = express();

require('./config/passport')(passport);

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, { useUnifiedTopology: true,useNewUrlParser: true });

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log('DB Connected!!!');
});


app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', require('./routes/index.js'));

app.get('/newblog', function(request, response){     //this is where i route my blog form
  response.render('blog')
})
app.use('/sucess', blgroutr) //this is where the submit button will direct me, but im getting 404

app.use('/registered', regroutr);
app.use('/profile', logroutr);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(function (err, response) {
  console.error(err.body)
  response.status(404).render('notfound', pages.notfound);
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log(`Listening on PORT ${PORT}`)
})
```

---

My Route for my blog post (`internalroute.js`) Either this wont detect my form or my form wont detect the file.

```js
const express = require('express');
const pgroutr = express.Router();
const blgschema = require('../models/blogschema');


pgroutr.post('/newblog', function(req, res){

  const usr = req.body.userna;
  const blgtt = req.body.title;
  const dtToday = req.body.date;
  const blgcont = req.body.blogcont;
  const newbPost = new blgschema(
    {
      username: usr,
      title: blgtt,
      date: dtToday,
      blog_cont: blgcont
    }
  );
  newbPost.save(function (err, newbPost){
    if (err) return res.render('error', pages.error);
    console.log('document added to collection')
    res.render('sucess')
  })
});

module.exports = pgroutr;
```

Comment: Your form post doesn't appear to have an `action` attribute to tell the browser what URL to post it to.  In your case, it looks like it should be `<form class="form-container" method="POST" action="/newblog">`.  Or, if you're using the `formaction` attribute on the submit button, then it needs to be the proper URL to hit your route.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Isnt it suppose to be ```<form class="form-container" method="POST" action="/sucess">``` as my lading page if i hit submit? because /newblog is where i access my form

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure which route you wanted it to go.  Note, you have a `formaction` attribute in the button which overrides the action attribute in the `<form>` tag.  Please use one and only one of those and point it at `/sucess`.  Then, in that `blgroutr`, you need a handler for `/` which you don't show.

Comment: It is odd that you're using external routers for single route handlers.  That's not really the right way to use routers.  Just export a single route handler if you only have one route to handle.  There's no reason to create a router for only a single route.

Comment: @jfriend00 so just put it inside the app.js file? because im also using other routes for the parts of my website, i want it externally so i can configure it easily.

Comment: @jfriend00 my blgroutr is my externalroutes.js which i defined on the very top of my app.js

Comment: You can still put it in a separate file if you want.  Just export the route handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up a solution where i removed the internalroutes file, and copied my codes from it and paste it directly in the app.js which is this part:

```
const blgschema = require('../models/blogschema');


pgroutr.post('/sucess', function(req, res){

  const usr = req.body.userna;
  const blgtt = req.body.title;
  const dtToday = req.body.date;
  const blgcont = req.body.blogcont;
  const newbPost = new blgschema(
    {
      username: usr,
      title: blgtt,
      date: dtToday,
      blog_cont: blgcont
    }
  );
  newbPost.save(function (err, newbPost){
    if (err) return res.render('error', pages.error);
    console.log('document added to collection')
    res.render('sucess')
  })
});
```

and change my EJS/HTML to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Blog" id="sub" formaction="/sucess">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML form appears to be submitting to the URL specified in the submit button by the `formaction` attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Blog" id="sub" formaction="sucess">
```

That should probably be `formaction="/sucess"` so it's not relative to the page URL.  In that case, it would get caught by this route definition in app.js:

```
app.use('/sucess', blgroutr)
```

So, that would send it to the `blgroutr` which you appear to be loading from:

```
const blgroutr = require('./routes/internalroutes')
```

Then, if we look in your internalroutes.js file, there's only one route and that's this one:

```
 pgroutr.post('/newblog', function(req, res){...}
```

For that to work, you would have to change your HTML to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Blog" id="sub" formaction="/sucess/newblog">
```

The path that the router was assigned to is added to the path specified in the router route definitions.

---

But, as I've said in comments, there really isn't any point in using a router for only a single route.  You can just export a single route handler.  If you ask me, the cleanest design would be this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Blog" id="sub" formaction="/createBlog">

const blgroutr = require('./routes/internalroutes')

app.post('/createBlog', blgroutr.createBlog);
```

And, then in the code for `blgroutr`, just export an object with individual route handlers on it.

---

P.S. I find your code extremely hard to read because you drop random letters from variable names that would otherwise be real words such as `sucess` and `pgroutr` and `blgroutr`.  It makes it mentally difficult to remember the exact spelling when typing code that should refer to them.  I'd prefer to see `success`, `pgrouter` and `blgrouter`.  Note, I recommended changing the action URL to `/createBlog` from `sucess` too because in the REST tradition, you'd like to make the URLs meaningfully descriptive.

Comment: thanks, i havent fixed it yet, but ill try what you suggest in your answer